# C program working and stop running at the same time?

Tags: c

## How can I run this program without any crash #C #CoFactors

This program is about finding cofactors of a number it is working but at the same time this program crashes after showing the output. Please take a look.

Here is the program.

```
int coFactors(int number,int divisor)
{
if(number%divisor==0)
{
    printf("%d ",divisor);
    number /= divisor;
    coFactors(number,divisor);
}
else if(number==divisor-1)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    coFactors(number,++divisor);
}    
             }                                 
           
int main()            
{                
int num;                  
printf("Enter number:");               
scanf("%d",&num);              
coFactors(num,2);

return 0;         
}
```

Comment: Compiler say *warning C4033: 'coFactors' must return a value*. That would apply to each of its three conditional code blocks.

Comment: Working and crashing in the same time... What? Sounds like a quantum computer.

Comment: 1) `int coFactors(` --> `void coFactors(`, Show your input.

Comment: Are you *quite sure* that the recursion will always hit a base case? I don't think it will.

Comment: try `if(number==divisor-1)` --> `if(number<divisor)`

Comment: E.g If you enter 27 in your code, recursion will not finish, So It's causing stack overflow.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why 27? 3 is plenty.

Comment: @EOF Anything is fine. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems below condition is wrong:

```
else if(number==divisor-1)
```

it should be:

```
else if(number < (divisor))
```

My earlier post would have avoided crashed but to get correct Co factor condition should have been like edited.

BLUEPIXY has suggested correctly.

Comment: Your original answer would **not** have avoided infinite descent for such unusual values as `1`.

Comment: True. Or the cases where value was less than divisor.